# Why is Float::INFINITY == Float::INFINITY in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

In mathematics 2 infinities are not equal, nor greater than or less then. So what gives?

In irb, Float::INFINITY == Float::INFINITY (tested in ruby 1.9.3)

Comment: Ruby is not math, and it's free to diverge from the rules of math as it pleases. In this case, you're comparing an object to itself. In programming terms, this *should be equal*.

Comment: `(0.0 / 0.0) == (0.0 / 0.0)` returns false, but `(10.0 / 0.0) == (10.0 / 0.0)` returns true, if anyone's curious.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm- Wouldn't the first be caused by the fact that 0.0 / 0.0 yields NaN, and NaN compares different from everything, including itself, while the second two both evaluate to +infinity?

Comment: `2 infinities are not equal, nor greater than or less then`: You are totally wrong. Same two infinities are equal, different ones are not. Since your question is based on a wrong premise, your question does not make sense.

Comment: It is not true that in math two infinities are not equal. For instance, you obtain the Riemann sphere by compactification of the complex plane, which adds a single point "called infinity" that you reach if you go far enough (if you look at stereographic projection and think about the North pole a bit, you'll see why it makes sense to have a single point infinity). I'm generally doing geometric computing, and its then natural to treat infinity as just another point. If two operations both get me to infinity, then they'd better be equal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In more technical terms, it all comes down to the IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetics.

> The IEEE 754 standard does implicitly define Infinity == Infinity to
>   be true. The relevant part of the standard is section 5.7: "Four
>   mutually exclusive relations are possible [between two IEEE 754
>   values]: less than, equal, greater than, and unordered. The last case
>   arises when at least one operand is NaN."
>
> Between any pair of floating point values exactly one of these four
>   relations is true. Therefore, since Infinity is not NaN, Infinity is
>   not unordered with respect to itself. Having one of (Infinity <
>   Infinity) and (Infinity > Infinity) be true wouldn't be consistent, so
>   (Infinity == Infinity).

This was taken from http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/98-07-134

Answer (score 6):

While there are multiple different infinities in most set theories, the infinities represented by real numbers typically represent the infinities of the [extended real number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), where +∞ and -∞ are values specifically chosen to be bigger than and smaller than all real numbers.  In this setup, ∞ = ∞ and -∞ = -∞.

The set theoretic infinities that are not equal are [cardinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) or [ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), which typically wouldn't be represented by a floating-point value.  They measure sizes and positions within sets, respectively, so would be better off as generalizations of another type, such as an integer type.  If you wanted to store those sorts of values, you would probably have a custom type representing an infinite ordinal or infinite cardinal number.

Also, it is definitely possible for set-theoretic infinities to equal one another.  ℵ<sub>0</sub> = ℵ<sub>0</sub>, for example (though ℵ<sub>0</sub> ≠ ℵ<sub>1</sub>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Most modern computers use IEEE Floating Point to represent real numbers.  These provide an approximation to real numbers, not the real thing.  In particular there are two values that represent all infinite values, +infinity and -infinity.  Just like you can't represent .1 or 1/3 totally accurately in binary, the infinities are approximations.

As such all +infinities are equal to each other and all -inifinities are equalto each other.